# order of JSON with multiple arrays in php with varying number of objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have never needed json previously, so I have almost zero experience...

I am outputting multiple arrays into a json file using the following code:

```
$file= 'myfile.json';

$contents = array('name' => $name,'busname' => $busname,'busdesc' => $busdesc, etc, etc);
    $newcont=json_encode($contents, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print_r($newcont);
    file_put_contents($file, $newcont);
```

This is working as expected, and the output gives me something similar to this:

```
"name": [
    "joe blogs",
    "random name 2",
    "random name 3",
    etc,
    etc
],
"busname": [

    "ABC business",
    "DEF business",
    "HIJ business",
    etc,
    etc
],
"busdesc": [
    "We do stuff",
    "We do other stuff",
    "We don't do anything",
    etc,
    etc
],
```

etc

Is it possible to (with a simple method) have the output to be more like:

```
"id1": [  "joe blogs", "ABC business", "We do stuff", etc ]
"id2":  [   "random name 2", "DEF business", "We do other stuff", etc ]
"id3":  [   "random name 3", "HIJ business", "We don't do anything", etc ]
etc
```

Layout is not particularly important, but getting them grouped together is.

I have had little success with getting relevant results from Google searches.

The reason I ask for a simple method, is that I am sure I can come up with some fancy loop that counts the number of entries first, then loops to keep adding the relevant data - and that may well be the answer, but I just wanted to know.

Many thanks

---

Edit:

I have undeleted this as my attempt at fixing did not work.

Here is the code:

```
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM membersites  WHERE id>0 ORDER BY id, busname");
$totalmem = mysqli_num_rows($results);
while($business = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $r1 = $business['id'];
    $id[]=$r1;
    $r2 = $business['name'];
    $name[]=$r2;
    $r4 = $business['busname'];
    $busname[]=$r4;
    $r5 = $business['busdesc'];
    $busdesc[]=$r5; 

    $all[] = "'id:''".$r1."''name:''".$r2."''busname:''".$r4."''busdesc:''".$r5."'";
}

$contents = array('members' => $all);
$newcont=json_encode($contents, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($newcont);
```

This almost worked as all the data is grouped correctly, however I am only getting one object (members) with all the users inside, not individual objects for each user.

Again, please bare in mind that this is the first project that I have had to output any json files.

Any help will be appreciated :)

---

Edit 2 (for clarity)

Final output needs to look like this

```
{
    [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"joe blogs",
            "busname":"ABC business",
            "busdesc":"We do stuff"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"joe blogs",
            "busname":"random name 2",
            "busdesc":"We do other stuff"
        },
        etc
    ]
}
```

This file is going to be read by a mobile app - the app developer has just told me that it need to be in this format.

Apologies for being awkward.

Comment: I'm sure you could do this at whatever point you put together `$name`, `$busname`, etc, etc.

Comment: The previous lines are reading the data from a database :
eg:  
while($business = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
 $result = $business['name'];
 $name[]=$result;
}

   I guess I could also create a new array at this point which has all these combined like you suggest - and just use this for the json creation?

Comment: That would be my suggestion. Generally such a structure would be more helpful than disparate lists of data anyway.

Comment: great idea... for some reason that never occurred to me. Thank you. If you like, you can repeat that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: No, the question is too broad and the answer too short to be of use to future visitors. I'd suggest just deleting it.

Comment: ok - will do. thanks again

Comment: undeleted as explained under edit.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with JSON. What you need to figure out is how to build a multidimensional array in the format that you require.

Comment: Could you please edit the question with the part of your code where you fetch the data from mysql and build the arrays?

Comment: Done, and am sure you are correct about the multidirectional array being needed. Would that be json_encoded the same way? Also, instead of using all[]=  can I use id[]=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you loop on your records from DB, build a multi-dimensional array:

```
while($business = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    $all[] = [
        'id' => $business['id'],
        'name' => $business['name'],
        'busname' => $business['busname'],
        'busdesc' => $business['busdesc'],
    ];
    // or 
    $all[] = $business;
    // or 
    $all[ $business['id'] ] = $business;
}
```

Then you can encode your multidimensional array into JSON like this:

```
$newcont = json_encode($all, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

the addition of `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` will preserve numerical keys (i.e. when you add using `$all[]`)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using PDO for database access instead of mysqli, which was originally developed as a stopgap replacement for the old mysql extension. But, using mysqli this should work:

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT id, name, busname, busdesc FROM membersites WHERE id > 0 ORDER BY id, busname");
$data = $result->fetch_all();
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

You should avoid using `SELECT *` when possible. It reduces overhead, and ensures that you know the order of columns you're receiving. The [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_all) function pulls all the records at once, so no need for a loop.